# cutting from string in C#

Tags: c#, string, treeview, substring

My strings look like that:  aaa/b/cc/dd/ee . I want to cut first part without a / . How can i do it? I have many strings and they don't have the same length. I tried to use Substring(), but what about / ?

I want to add 'aaa' to the first treeNode, 'b' to the second etc. I know how to add something to treeview, but i don't know how can i receive this parts.

Comment: given your example, what is the desired output?

Comment: Do you want to get first part or get rid of the first part? If former, then you can do: "aaa/b/cc/dd/ee".Split('/')[0]

Comment: I can almost guarantee this is a homework assignment.  The simplest method of doing this would be to handle each sub-string and place it in an array.  You can loop through the string in parts by using a while loop and a counting integer.  Once you build the array you can go from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method is what you're after?

```
string value = "aaa/b/cc/dd/ee";

string[] collection = value.Split('/');
```

> Identifies the substrings in this instance that are delimited by one or more characters specified in an array, then places the substrings into a String array.

Based on your updates related to a TreeView (ASP.Net? WinForms?) you can do this:

```
foreach(string text in collection)
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(text);
    myTreeView.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Substring` and `IndexOf` to find the location of the first `/`

To get the first part:

```
// from memory, need to test :)
string output = String.Substring(inputString, 0, inputString.IndexOf("/"));
```

To just cut the first part:

```
// from memory, need to test :)
string output = String.Substring(inputString, 
                                 inputString.IndexOf("/"),     
                                 inputString.Length - inputString.IndexOf("/");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to do:

```
string[] parts = "aaa/b/cc/dd/ee".Split(new char[] { '/' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a job for... [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions)!

Comment: Old chinese proverb: "Faced with problem, programmer might decide to use Regular Expression. Programmer now have 2 problem". :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by using `string.Split` to split your string into an array, and then `string.Join` to make whatever parts of the array you want into a new string.

For example:

```
var parts = input.Split('/');
var processedInput = string.Join("/", parts.Skip(1));
```

This is a general approach. If you only need to do very specific processing, you can be more efficient with `string.IndexOf`, for example:

```
var processedInput = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```